# How would I detect touches in bottom left 20% of screen Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to detect touch in only a specific area of the screen. When I have the condition

```
"touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2"
```

then I get it works for half of the screen on the x axis but when I try to add the height condition it does not work

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2 && touch.position.y / 2 < Screen.height)
        {
            Debug.Log("Touch");
        }
    }
```

Comment: typo error maybe?  touch.position.y / 2 < Screen.height -> touch.position.y  < Screen.height / 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just FYI:

```
touch.position.y / 2 < Screen.height;
```

is already true...so i suppose you want to write this line :

```
touch.position.y  < Screen.height / 2;
```

in this case only the upper left part of screen is touchable

Comment: Oh wow what a simple mistake. I divided in the wrong area. Thank you sir!

Comment: don't forget to validate the answer to close the question..glad to help you